# Why do we get the build error "error C2065: 'ostringstream' : undeclared identifier" & How to fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, iostream, ostream

Hi I am compilinig a C++ solution in VS2008.

```
 ostringstream      strout;
```

I am getting the compilation error "*error C2065: 'ostringstream' : undeclared identifier*".

I feel I have included all the necessary header files.

Can anyone kindly let me know how to fix this error (What all header files to include) ?

Also I am getting a strange error like *"error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'strout'*" at the same line.

Whereas I know that I havent missed ";" semi-colon @ the line whre the error is being thrown.

Thanks IN advance.

Comment: You need to include `<sstream>` and either add `using namespace std;` or explicitly qualify the name with `sed::` (i.e. use `std::ostringstream`).

Comment: The stringstreams are in the header `<sstream>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't tell you what's wrong with your code for sure, unless you show it to us.

But you can use the following and an example on how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Hello";
    std::cout << oss.str() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The most *likely* cause is that you *haven't* actually included all the needed header files which is why it wouldn't recognise `ostringstream`.

And it's that lack of recognition that's probably causing the missing semicolon error.

Answer (score 8):

You need to

```
#include <sstream>
```

and qualify the name `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Thank u. I too had used <iostream.h> which was throwing a diff set of errors. Now I didnt use the suffix ".h" and it worked fine.