# Store hex value as string (Arduino project)

Tags: c++, arduino, hex, store

I'm working on an Arduino project and I want to store a hex value as string.

eg: Hex is C697C63B

```
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
     Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
}
```

I would like to store the String as `x = "C697C63B";`

```
  String CardID = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    CardID += (buffer[i],HEX);
    Serial.println(CardID);
  }
```

But the Sting is stored as `CardID = 16161616`

Sorry I just start C++ for a week and I spend 3 day already just to find answer.

Okay i found the answer now thank you everyone that help

```
  String CardID = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
    CardID += String(buffer[i], HEX);
  Serial.print(CardID);
```

Comment: `CardID += (buffer[i],HEX);` doesn't do what you think it does. Read up on [comma operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). In addition, you need to provide [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `ostringstream`:

```
auto outstr = std::ostringstream{};
outstr << std::hex << 0xC697C63Bul;
auto myHexString = outstr.str();
```

Comment: sorry this **ostringstream** don't work in my arduino project do you have another idea?

Comment: @user1437099 You probably missed to add `#include <sstream>`? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9850537/1879699

Comment: already try 
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
but it can't

Comment: Doesn't your environment include a complete C++ standard library?

Answer (score 0):

[std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) + IO manipulator [hex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) may be want you want.

Comment: sorry this **ostringstream** don't work in my arduino project do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use c-style sprintf :

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, "%08x", HEX);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int nHex = 0xC697C63B;
  char pHexStr[100];
  sprintf(pHexStr,"%x",nHex);
  fprintf(stdout, "%s", pHexStr);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple in Arduino Programming Language to convert hex to be a string.

Just doing:

```
char StringValue[ ]=String(0xFF,HEX)
```

Comment: Using ESP32, I receive a "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer" error message on compile.